# Check selected dropdown with jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms

I am trying to create a jquery function that controlls my form appearance. I am creating a view in rails where you can create buy/sell orders, and depending on which you choose the form will look different.

Here is the relevant part of my view:

```
<%= form_for @trade_order do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :type, 'Buy or sell?'%>
  <%= f.select :type, [['Buy','buy'],['Sell','sell']] %>
</div>
<script>
  $('#trade_order_type').change(function() {
    if($(this.val() == "buy"){
      $('#buy').show();
      $('#sell').hide();
    }else{
      $('#buy').hide();
      $('#sell').show();
    }
  });
</script>
<div id="buy">
  <div class="field">
.....
```

The buy/sell divs is what I aim to hide/show depending on what the user has selected.
The code works up till the if statement. But I just cant understand why it will not work.

If someone please could take a look at this and throw me a bone you would make my day!

Comment: Perhaps a typo, but your selector is missing a closing parenthesis, $(this).val().

Comment: can you show your buy/show divs please?

Comment: @DerekS perhaps that is the issue notice the statement `The code works up till the if statement.`

Comment: Hahahaha, you are right. I have been sitting with this all afternoon and trying different solutions. But must say that it is my first time with jquery. Even called a friend who works with it and he couldn't see anything wrong. But sometimes I guess you are just blind for whats in front of you. Thanks.

Comment: Derek S got it... was a simple typo. And I have spent 5 hours on it :( Trying whole different solutions :(